# Counting specific values for individual years in a graph database

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to count how many baptisms and marriages took place in a particular church in a particular year. Doing this is not so hard and this query allows me to do so (e.g. for the year 1702):

```
MATCH (e:baptism)-[:TOOK_PLACE_IN]->(ch:church:Church_of_Utrecht {Name: 'De Noteboom'})
WHERE 1701 < e.Event_year < 1703
RETURN count (e:baptism) AS Number_of_baptisms
```

However, when wanting to do this for a period of 50 years, it quickly becomes very time consuming. I would like to have a query like the above one but which does this calculation for each year in a given period (say from 1700 to 1750) and gives the output in two columns (year and number of baptisms). I reckon I'll need to use a FOR EACH statement, but I'm completely stuck. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's easier than you think. You just need to throw the year into the return statement. Cypher automatically groups based on the return values (this is also a gotcha if you don't want this behavior, so beware of that).

So your query becomes:

```
MATCH (e:baptism)-[:TOOK_PLACE_IN]->(ch:church:Church_of_Utrecht {Name: 'De Noteboom'})
WHERE 1700 =< e.Event_year <= 1750
RETURN e.Event_year as Year, count(distinct e) AS Number_of_baptisms
```

You can read more about this behavior in the [Aggregating Functions](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/aggregating/) section of the Cypher Manual.

Comment: My God, I was thinking about way too complex solutions! Many thanks!!

Comment: I had the same problem when I was starting. Still find myself overcomplicating things sometimes.